# a hypothesis test for evidence that one thing is dependant on another

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm not sure what the null hypothesis for this would be/ what the correct symbols are.
the data is unpaired and I'm needing to find if there evidence ( at 5% level of significance) that one thing is dependant on another.

for example, is there evidence that the size of the banana is dependant on the plantation its grown in?

H0:
 H1:

Answer (score 1):

You might use Chi-Square Test for Independence.

Considering the independence of size of banana and  the plantation its grown in.
For simplification, let's assume that those bananas are dividing into $r$ groups according to its size and are grown in $s$ plantations. Denote $A_1, A_2..A_r$ for size level, $B_1, B_2...B_s$ for plantation level. Then we obtain a $r \times s$ contingency table.

[image: contingency table]

Denote $p_{ij}$ for the probability that bananas are from $A_i$ and $B_j$,   $p_{i.}$ for the probability that bananas are from $A_i$, $p_{.j}$ for the probability that bananas are from $B_j$.

Hypothesis: $ H_0: p_{ij} = p_{i.}p_{.j}$and $H_1: p_{ij} \neq p_{i.}p_{.j} $

$$ 
T_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{r} \sum_{j = 1}^{s} \frac {(nX_{ij} - m_in_j)^2}{nm_in_j} 
$$

If $H_0$ is correct, $T_n \xrightarrow{d.f.} {\chi}^2_{(r-1)(s-1)}$ when $n$ is sufficiently big.

You might see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence) for more information.